# Can I get an EASA Class 2 medical if I have monocular vision?

Tags: medical, easa

I have monocular vision (amblyopia) and I want to get the EASA Class 2 medical certificate to do the private pilot license. Will I be able to pass the exam?

Comment: As a side note, Carlos Dardano the captain of TACA 110 had monocular vision. This was the 737 that landed on the levee in New Orleans when both engines flamed out during a thunderstorm in 1988. Dardono lost the use of his left eye three years earlier when a bullet went into the cockpit of the cargo DC-3 that he was flying during the Civil War in El Salvador. Carlos  Dardano retired earlier this month after 49 years in commercial aviation, and 38 years after losing vision in one eye.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, possibly. As always with anything medical the key is to speak to an AME. You don't necessarily have to have a full on medical - many will give you some advice/info before you book it.

The relevant info you probably want is:

> In an applicant with amblyopia, the visual acuity of the amblyopic eye should be 6/18
> (0,3) or better. The applicant may be assessed as fit, provided the visual acuity in the
> other eye is 6/6 (1,0) or better, with or without correction, and no significant pathology
> can be demonstrated.
> <sub>source: https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/downloads/1535/en</sub>

If it gives you any confidence I have Amblyopia too, with my vision also corrected using glasses, and I have never had a problem getting a class 2 medical. Over the years I've had an faa, an easa and a uk caa class 2.

Comment: Got my medical just yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

Medical regulations are complicated, but based solely on the information from your question, it should be possible to obtain EASA Class 2 (but not Class 1).

[EASA rules](https://www.easa.europa.eu/en/easy-access-rules-medical-requirements), section "AMC2 MED.B.070 (c)" allow monocular applicants, subject to a few conditions:

> Reduced vision in one eye or monocularity: Applicants with reduced
> vision or loss of vision in one eye may be assessed as fit if:
>
> (1) the binocular visual field or, in the case of monocularity, the
> monocular visual field is acceptable;
>
> (2) in the case of monocularity, a period of adaptation time has
> passed from the known point of visual loss, during which the applicant
> should be assessed as unfit;
>
> (3) the unaffected eye achieves distant visual acuity of 6/6 (1,0),
> corrected or uncorrected;
>
> (4) the unaffected eye achieves intermediate visual acuity of N14 or
> equivalent and N5 or equivalent for near (Refer to GM1 MED.B.070);
>
> (5) there is no significant ocular pathology in the unaffected eye;
> and
>
> (6) a medical flight test is satisfactory.

Based on my own experience (one eye amblyopic, visual acuity as low as 0,1), they asked to undergo an extensive eye examination with an ophthalmologist and a medical flight test (my AME referred me to both). It was successful at the end, but took a lot of time.